# Javascript and JSON

Tags: javascript, json

This will work :

```
var json = { 'items': [{ 'id': 72, 'quantity': 1, 'format': '90ml' }, { 'id': 72, 'quantity': 4, 'format': '70ml'}] }
alert(json.items[1].id);
```

This will NOT work :

```
var json = $.cookie('json_string');
alert(json.items[1].id);
```

the json_string in the cookie is EXACTLY the same as in example #1. After fooling around, I realized I need to do this to make it work:

```
    eval("var json = " + $.cookie("json_cart"));
```

Is this the correct way to do it? It seems like a hack, im facing some challenges when trying to make this javascript / c# json communication, i tought it would be very easy. Anyway. At least I got it running now.

Comment: No, the json_string in the cookie is a string. In example #1 it's an object literal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## This is *NORMAL*

- In your first case, you are using an **[object literal](http://www.json.org/js.html)**.
- In the second case, this is a string containing data formatted using the **[JSON data-interchange format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)**.

To de-serialize the string to an object, and assuming you target modern browsers, you could use the native function to do:

```
var myObj = JSON.parse($.cookie('json_string'));
```

Or you could import [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) from the [official JSON website](http://www.json.org/) and use the same line as above.

Or, [as mentioned by subhaze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346451/javascript-and-json/4346512#4346512), you can be completely jQuery-y and use:

```
var myObj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
```

---

### A Note About URL-Encoding

If the string is encoded in the cookie, then you need to decode it first, using [`decodeURIComponent()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeURIComponent.asp) like this:

```
var myObj = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent($.cookie('json_string')))
```

### A Note About Quoted Keys

Your [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is actually invalid, as it requires double-quoted keys. You should use **double-quotes** (`"`) to wrap around your keys and your string values.

### Check It

To quickly check for the validity of your JSON, try [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

---

*Your question is very similar to others. So, in the future, be sure to check for similar questions first by checking the [JSON tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json) or [searching for your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=parsing+a+json+string).*

Comment: +1, except that I'd say the second case is a string containing JSON - JSON string seems to imply that it is a special type of string.

Comment: umm i get Unexpected token ILLEGAL when using your example

Comment: @Skilldrick: Thanks for bringing that to my attention. Fixed.

Comment: @Etienne Dupuis: what browser?

Comment: @Etienne Dupuis: Works fine for me. Chrome has native support for JSON.parse and JSON.stringify. Do you have jQuery?

Comment: The string seems encoded in the cookies : %20 instead of spaces etc. Yes i do have jquery. I think i need to decode the string before parsing it. Even tho a ALERT() will output it right

Comment: @Etienne Dupuis: So I guess "json_string in the cookie is EXACTLY the same as in example #1" was not that true after all :) You'll need to use JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent($.cookie('json_string'))) then.

Comment: OMG i found out, the encoding was fine, I was using Single quote on my JSON file, which is invalid!!. THanks for all this man, but wow its been a strugling for me for the past hours for double quotes...........

Comment: I went through the trouble of making this example using JSON2.js so figured i'd post it even though all is resolved :P maybe someone else not using a JS framework will find it beneficial as well http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/Ff6yj/

Comment: @subhaze: nice :) Never really have the reflex of using jsfiddle. Guess I'm not enough of a JS programmer.

Answer (score 4):

**Notice**

For either of these two methods to work your `String` **must** be written as valid JSON.

In your example you need to wrap your keys in double-quotes `"` not single `'`.

```
{"key":value}
```

---

It looks as though you're using jQuery, if so. This should work.

**jQuery**: [Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/tYa2C/)

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

Example obtained from [jQuery parseJson](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

---

As [haylem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346476/javascript-and-json/4346476#4346476) stated, if you're not using a library **[json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)** would work:

**json2**: [Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/nuces/)

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"name":"John"}');
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

Comment: {'items':[{'id':72,'quantity':1,'format':'90ml'},{'id':72,'quantity':4,'format':'70ml'}] }      results in : Invalid JSON:

Comment: you need to make you `'` single quotes `"` doubles for it to be a valid JSON object http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/E2S7K/

Comment: awesome! in plain JS you can use `'` or if it's not a reserved-word no `'` or `"` if it's structured as a valid variable name and JS will accept it. However, when using parsers they're strict on how the JSON is formed so you have to make sure all your `keys` are wrapped in `"` for it to consider it well formed and parse it.

Answer (score 2):

No. Use [`json2.js`](http://www.json.org/js.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should parse the content of your cookie. Poor man's solution says to eval() it, since json is valid javascript syntax. Good developer's solutions says to use [a library](http://www.json.org/js.html) to parse json :)

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using jQuery. Don't use `eval` because it can be unsafe; use [$.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).